# How to implement MVC Pager?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, pager

I am using [MvcPAger](http://en.webdiyer.com/MvcPager) in MVC application.

MvcPager Refrence added in my application

MY VIEW

```
@model  Webdiyer.WebControls.Mvc.PagedList<MvcApplicationdyncat.Models.ProductModel>
<div class="page-list">
   @Html.Pager(Model, new Webdiyer.WebControls.Mvc.PagerOptions { PageIndexParameterName = "page", FirstPageText = "First", ShowPrevNext = true, ShowFirstLast = true, PrevPageText = "Prev", NextPageText = "Next", LastPageText = "Last", CurrentPagerItemWrapperFormatString = "<a href='#' class='selected'>{0}</a>" })
</div>
```

Controller :

```
using Webdiyer.WebControls.Mvc;
PagedList<ProductModel> pagedList = productModels.ToPagedList<ProductModel>(num, this.ProductListPageSize);
return View(pagedList);
```

My question is

1>If we are adding mvcpager reference in project and  also in view so why we are not found "Pager" extension after @Html. ?
2>Any other reference is required for Pager ?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? It sounds like you have a problem with the `@Html.Pager...` line, right?

Comment: @ Ohlin yes, I got error :  @Html.Pager... line 28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this statement on the first line in your view:

```
@using Webdiyer.WebControls.Mvc
```

Do you use the MvcPager code files in your project? Or do you have them as a separate project that you compile into a dll? If you have them in your own project you have to put them in the right folder. You can create a folder named MvcPager and put all of them there. If you put the files in the wrong folder they might not compile and then you can't use them.

Comment: Great :-) If you're using the DLL then you only need to add the @using statement. You don't need to think of where you're putting the source code, because you don't use the source code.